# Litle problem with assigning subscriber

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I have a subscriber that looks like this

---

```
rclcpp::Subscription<minicar_control::msg::Feedback>::SharedPtr hw_feedback_sub;
...
hw_feedback_sub = this->create_subscription<minicar_control::msg::Feedback>("hw_feedback", 1000, std::bind(&STMRobotHW::feedbackCallback, this, _1));
```

---

As far as I know this should work, but this is how problem looks in VS Code:

> operand types are: std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Subscription<minicar_control::msg::Feedback, std::allocator, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<minicar_control::msg::Feedback, std::allocator>>> = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Subscription<const minicar_control::msg::Feedback &, std::allocator, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<const minicar_control::msg::Feedback &, std::allocator>>>

I think, that this can be solved by removing hw_feedback_sub from header and use auto like this

---

```
auto hw_feedback_sub = this->create_subscription<minicar_control::msg::Feedback>("hw_feedback", 1000, std::bind(&STMRobotHW::feedbackCallback, this, _1));
```

---

But I want to know where I overlook mistake. Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408331/litle-problem-with-assigning-subscriber./) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-21**:
The `rclcpp::Subscription` should be a class member. Removing it from header and using `auto` (the way you suggested), may avoid the error, but the callback will not be executed. On the other hand, I can not reproduce the error, as the code is incomplete. I suggest creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I manage to solve this problem. The issue was feedbackCallback method. Wrong version:

---

```
void feedbackCallback(const minicar_control::msg::Feedback &fb_msg);
```

---

Right version:

---

```
void feedbackCallback(const minicar_control::msg::Feedback::SharedPtr fb_msg);
```

---

@ravijoshi, thank you for your help. I didn't thought, that callback will not be executed.

---

Originally posted by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) with karma: 95 on 2022-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-24**:
I am glad you made it work. This is why I encourage creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example)